# Startup.cs method app.MapSignalR() not generating hubs in signalR-2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, signalr, asp.net-4.5

I'm getting 404 not found error since browser is unable to find /signalr/hubs. I'm using signalR-2.0.0-rc1 in a normal web application (not mvc). Following is the the related web.config settings

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="SignalRHubServer.Startup, SignalRHubServer" />
</appSettings>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Client code (/signalr/hubs used both ways):

```
<head>
  <title>SignalR Echo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0-rc1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("signalr/hubs") %>'></script>-->
</head>
```

Startup.cs is as below:

```
namespace SignalRHubServer
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {            
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
  }
}
```

When i debug, the breakpoint at app.MapSignaR() does get hit, but still i get the same 404 error. Following is a hub declaration

```
namespace SignalRHubServer
{
  public class MyChatHub : Hub
  {
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
  }
}
```

I migrated the application from SignalR-1.1.3 and have removed the MapHubs() call from global.asax.cs. I have also uninstalled the related SignalR nuget packages. However, with SignalR-1.1.3 it used to work fine.

Can anyone suggest what i might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this working, i had to revert to SignalR-1.1.3. I couldn't get it to work with the SignalR-2.0-rc1 beta release.

However with SignalR-2.0, stable release in nuget on Oct/17/2013, everything is working fine.

Comment: if it's working fine with 2.0, why did you have to revert to 1.1.3 ?

Comment: Hope your read answer properly. I had to revert to 1.1.3 when i was using 2.0-RC1 before a stable version of 2.0 was released.